# Why are higher magic numbers not accurately predicted if nuclear potential is assumed to be a central potential?

Tags: nuclear-physics, potential, stability, binding-energy, isotopes

Nuclei with magic numbers have a higher stability that those without. If we think of the nuclear potential as a central potential though these magic numbers aren't predicted accurately. Why is this so?

Comment: I don't understand, why would the fact that the central is potential imply the availability to predict these numbers? The things is that some potentials have been tested to see if the the magic numbers arose from these, which are the square-well potential, the harmonic oscillator, and the Woods-Saxon potential (which I think was the most accurate when predicting the numbers, but I don't quite remember, that's why I'm commenting, not answering).

Answer (score 1):

> If we think of the nuclear potential as a central ...

One should not think that N-N potential is **only** a central attractive one.

The test of the potential form and nature has been done when one tries to

reproduce two nucleon binding energy and other properties of deuteron ground

state.

The initial trial is done with central potential like a square well but later to explain the **quadrupole moment** of deuteron non-central terms do come into play. A small D-state contribution is observed.

Moreover, the Nuclear forces are **spin-dependent** (As amply shown by the scattering results of  Nucleon with Ortho and para-Hydrogen molecule ).
Therefore for a realistic potential, the spin-orbit interaction also comes into play.

Therefore the Shell model was attempted with potentials of the form of a square well as well as the harmonic oscillator form but they failed to reproduce the higher magic number.(they could  show only 2, 8, 20 as the completely filled shells)

With the inclusion of spin-orbit term of the type  **-f(r). (l.s)** 
the shell  model reproduces the experimental  magic  numbers namely

2, 8, 20, 28, 50, 82 ,126 ,184

> ref.https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/nuclear-engineering/22-02-introduction-to-applied-nuclear-physics-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT22_02S12_lec_ch5.pdf

Comment: So higher magic numbers aren't accurately predicted when we think of the nuclear potential as a central potential because we also need the spin-orbit term to describe the potential?

Comment: @mesquared-As one does shell model with central potentials the shell closures occur at 2,8,20,40,70,112,168 but as soon as one invokes the spin-orbit effects certain levels like 2p and 1f,1g ... they split and their energy values are such that reflects the magic numbers. I think its due to the effect of strong coupling as one goes to higher levels vis-a-vis the central part of the N-N potentials.

Comment: @mcsquared Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model